# How to start TensorFlow Serving ModelServer with the REST API endpoint

Tags: rest, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to make use of the new possibility to send HTTP requests to the TensorFlow ModelServer. However, when I try to run the following, it doesn't recognize the --rest_api_port argument:

```
tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 \
   --model_name=half_plus_three \
   --model_base_path=$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_three/

unknown argument: --rest_api_port=8501
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same error. I looked through the source code.

In `main.cc` file, there is no `rest_api_port` option in the source code version r1.7 below.

Due to this, if you want to use REST, you need to use **tensorflow-serving r1.8** above or implement it your self.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Do you have a good method for checking the tensorflow-serving version? Turns out I was having problems because I tried to run on a AWS Deep Learning AMI and even though it seems to say it updated to the latest version, apparently somehow it didn't. (if I try upgrade, it says tensorflow-model-server already latest version 1.8)

Comment: @CSquare Then, do you build tensorflow-model-server on your own using bazel? or download and install it using like apt-get? If you get the error you mentioned earlier, installed version of tensorflow-serving is not version 1.8. Please tell me which method you used to install it.

Comment: I tried "pip install --upgrade" as recommended in the user guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/updating-software.html) I tried apt-get but the DL AMI comes with tensorflow pre-installed and it seems when I use apt-get it installs it all over (not seeing the previous installation?) but functionally it doesn't make a difference. I'm not sure how to see where installations go to and the program is called from. I worked around the issue by instead taking an AMI that doesn't have these pre-installations and install tensorflow serving myself.